# Trigger NullPointerException Error

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

while executing this trigger I am getting this error:

> docketingactionduplicateupdate: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Trigger.docketingactionduplicateupdate.

```
trigger docketingactionduplicateupdate  on Docketing_Rule_Action__c (before update) {

    set<string> SETaction = NEW set<string>();


    for(Docketing_Rule_Action__c DRA : [select ID,Name,Docketing_Rule_Master__c from Docketing_Rule_Action__c where id !=: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ])
    {

        string docketingaction = DRA.Name+DRA.Docketing_Rule_Master__c;


        SETaction.add(docketingaction);
    }
    for(Docketing_Rule_Action__c DRAtoInsert:Trigger.new)
    {

        string docketingaction = DRAtoInsert.Name+DRAtoInsert.Docketing_Rule_Master__c;


        if(SETaction.contains(docketingaction))
        {
            DRAtoInsert.adderror('Action Name for this Docketing Rule Master already exists');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error I assume (you did not include line number)

because the trigger is executing outside of a UI/VF context and thus this is null:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
```

You need to check that `ApexPages.CurrentPage()` is not null. In fact, I am not all sure you can even use an `ApexPages` within a trigger but I have never tried (it makes sense that you could, but I see a case where it should not be as well), maybe you can but there would be many times when it would be null.

Maybe add:

```
if(ApexPages.currentPage() == null) return;
```

to the beginning of your trigger to exit completely as it appears your entire trigger is based on the availability of that parameter being present

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way that you can ever use ApexPages inside a trigger, even if it did originate from a VF controller action.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Yea, i thought as much. Thanks for clarifying.